# Cmake with WSL and VS2019

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to compile a C++ program using WSL in Windows10/Ubuntu/VS2019. When I try to build the program I'm getting following errors.

CMake generation started for configuration: 'WSL-GCC-Debug'.

> Found cmake executable at $HOME/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake.

> $HOME/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/mnt/d/Work/j/install/"  /mnt/d/Work/j/CMakeLists.txt;

> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/s/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:185 (configure_file):

> [CMake]   configure_file Problem configuring file

> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):

> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)

> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0

> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/s/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:222 (configure_file):

> [CMake]   configure_file Problem configuring file

> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):

> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)

> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0

> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/s/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:220 (configure_file):

> [CMake]   configure_file Problem configuring file

> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):

> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)

> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info

> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed

> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc

> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - works

> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features

> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done

> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/s/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:82 (configure_file):

> [CMake]   configure_file Problem configuring file

> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):

> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)

> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info

> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed

> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++

> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - works

> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features

> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done

> [CMake] CMake Error at /home/s/.vs/cmake/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:75 (configure_file):

> [CMake]   configure_file Problem configuring file

> [CMake] Call Stack (most recent call first):

> [CMake]   CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)

> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

> [CMake] See also "/mnt/d/Work/j/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

> [CMake] See also "/mnt/d/Work/j/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

> [CMake]

> cd /mnt/d/Work/j/build;$HOME/.vs/cmake/bin/cmake -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="/mnt/d/Work/j/install/"  /mnt/d/Work/j 2>&1; returned with exit code: 1

> 

I'm using following Build Configuration.

```
{
  "name": "WSL-GCC-Debug",
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "configurationType": "Debug",
  "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\",
  "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\install\\",
  "cmakeExecutable": "cmake",
  "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
  "buildCommandArgs": "",
  "ctestCommandArgs": "",
  "inheritEnvironments": [ "linux_x64" ],
  "wslPath": "${defaultWSLPath}",
  "addressSanitizerRuntimeFlags": "detect_leaks=0",
  "variables": [],
  "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was missing zip tool from WSL.

> sudo apt install g++ gdb make rsync zip

Installing the command fixed it